# Why my document.getElementById('someText').innnerHTML Not displaying But Console was fine

Tags: javascript

```
console.log('hello test');
//alert("yoyo");

//Variables
//var b = '';

//change the element of html

document.getElementById('someText').innnerHTML = 'Hey there';
```

I learn the basic javascript tutorial from YouTube Clever Programmer but it seems like my javascript cannot work although I follow 100% exactly the same code as his type.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

 <p id="someText"></p>  
    <script src="home.js">
        //alert('test');
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you tell us if the code at the start of your post is in a file called "home.js" and is it in the same directory as the file with the HTML?

Comment: You have a typo

Answer (score 1):

Typo in `innerHTML`. `document.getElementById('someText').innnerHTML` needs to be `document.getElementById('someText').innerHTML = 'Hey there';`